# How to create and append new dataframe in one line?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create a dataframe once but append to it many time?

I have two dataframes in my script. staging pulls information from an API ( i am testing logic with csv) on a daily basis and performs calculations on it. permanent appends the rows of staging based on the calculations. Staging will always have changing rows and values and permanent will always be permanent only appending new rows into it.

Code So far:

```
import pandas as pd


staging = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/test.csv').dropna(axis = 0, how='all')


permanent = pd.DataFrame()

    for data in staging:
        permanent=permanent.append(staging,ignore_index=False).drop_duplicates()
```

but everytime the script runs the line of code to create a blank permanent df gets run and empties permanent df back to (0,0). **How do I only create permanent once and constantly append to it?**

Comment: Where is your data?

Comment: added code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your code structured?

If `permenant = pd.DataFrame()` is in a loop, take that outside of the loop:

```
permenant = pd.DataFrame()
while fetch_data:
    # ...append permenant with staging data... #
```

If you're running the script anew every time, of course it reasons that your `permenant` will be empty because nothing is in memory.  Export your `permenant` to your format of choice (e.g. `csv` or `pickle`) and then load it up based on your format selected:

```
permenant = pd.read_csv('myfile')

# ...append permenant with staging data... #

permenant = pd.to_csv('myfile')
quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I took your advice and put the code I was running into a loop. See above I made some edits. However when I declare permanent df outside of a loop it is still being cleared. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Again, every time you execute your script, `permanent` is empty because you are just defining it at that point.  You have to actually write your `permanent` to somewhere outside the script so that the next time you run your script, you can load it back up.

Comment: i put it outside the while loop I have and it worked perfectly. thank you.